Pressure drop in a planar helical pipe
I have a question about hydrodynamic pressure drop in a planar spiral coiled pipe flow. Please consider a pipe of diameter D which has multiple centric turns. All turns are in a same plane. The pitch between each two neighbor turns is P. The radial distance between the center and the innermost turn (radius of the innermost turn) is R1 and the radial distance between the center and the outermost turn (radius of the outermost turn) is R2. The velocity of the fluid at the entrance of the pipe is V. Density and dynamic viscosity of the fluid are known. Flow inside the pipe is always remain laminar. I found these formulas for the hydrodynamic pressure drop on internet. Since I do not have any reference for them, I am not sure about them. Could you please help me by providing a reference for them or suggesting some referred formulas.
Eu * G=49*(Re^-0.67)
G=P*(D^0.5)/((R2*(R2-R1))^0.75)

How can you find these but have no reference from where you found them. Sounds like BS of the first order.
